# Hidden directory detected apache 2.4

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I found a security related issue in apache 2.4. When i amtrying to hit the below link in the browser url-

http://example.com/aux/

http://example.com/cgi-bin/

http://example.com/com2/

http://example.com/com1/

I am getting:-

**Forbidden 403
You don't have permission to access /com2 on this server.**

How can i redirect from 403 permission denied to 402 page not found?

Answer (score 0):

One of the many ways:

```
AliasMatch ^/(aux|cgi-bin|com1|com2)/ /doesnotexist
```

Answer (score 0):

For Non-SSL (Keep inside `httpd.conf` and `IfModule mod_rewrite.c`)

```
RewriteRule /(com[1-9]|aux|con)/?$ /404 [L,NC]
```

For SSL (Keep inside `httpd-ssl.conf` and `VirtualHost`)

```
RewriteRule /(com[1-9]|aux|con)/?$ /404 [L,NC]
```